# Convert Maps.difference(firstMap, secondMap) to Map in java

Tags: java, guava

I have a Java code to find the difference between two JSON strings. As shown below:

```
String afterString = converterUtil.convertObjectToJson(targetObject);
        Gson g = new Gson();
        Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {
        }.getType();
        Map<String, Object> firstMap = g.fromJson(beforeString, mapType);
        Map<String, Object> secondMap = g.fromJson(afterString, mapType);
        System.out.println(Maps.difference(firstMap, secondMap));
```

How can I save the difference result as a map which is returned by `Maps.difference`?

Answer (score 3):

From [Guava's `Maps` documentation](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html), [`Maps#difference`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#difference-java.util.Map-java.util.Map-) returns a [`MapDifference`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MapDifference.html).  To convert this to a `Map`, you can use [`MapDifference#entriesDiffering`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MapDifference.html#entriesDiffering--).  There also exist other methods which may be useful to you such as [`MapDifference#entriesInCommon`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MapDifference.html#entriesInCommon--), [`MapDifference#entriesOnlyOnLeft`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MapDifference.html#entriesOnlyOnLeft--), and [`MapDifference#entriesOnlyOnRight`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MapDifference.html#entriesOnlyOnRight--).

Comment: The API documantation of `MapDifference.entriesDiffering()` [link](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/collect/MapDifference.html#line.59) says: "Returns an unmodifiable map describing keys that appear in both maps, but with different values." If  "different values" is based on `hashCode` and `equals` and the JSON contains objects and no corresponding custom types are registered that override `hashCode` and `equals`, all such objects will be different. Right?